# Is there a way in springboot/hibernate to automatically detect when a related entity is updated, similar to the @PreUpdate annotation?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm looking to keep a record of different fields of a entity for use in some business logic, which can be easily done using the @PreUpdate annotation. However, this is only triggered when fields that are directly on the entity are changed, but not on related entities. Here an example entity User class:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Transient
    private User loadState;

    @Column
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column
    private LocalDate phoneNumberChanged;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    List<Address> addresses;

    @Column
    private LocalDate addressesChanged;

    @PreUpdate
    public void updateRecords() {
        keepLastPhoneNumber();   // save date that phone number was changed
        keepLastAddresses();     // save date that addresses were changed
    }

    @PostLoad
    private void storeState() {
        loadState = new User();
        loadState.setphoneNumber(this.getPhoneNumber());
        loadState.setAddresses(new Address(this.getAddresses()));
    }

    private void keepLastPhoneNumber() {
        if (!loadState.getPhoneNumber().equals(this.getPhoneNumber())) {
            this.setPhoneNumberChanged(LocalDate.now());
        }
    }

    private void keepLastAddresses() {
        if (!loadState.getAddresses().equals(this.getAddresses())) {
            this.setAddressesChanged(LocalDate.now());
        }
    }
}
```

So here when phoneNumber is changed the `updateRecords()` function is run, but when the addresses field is changed it is not. Is there a way to run that function when a change is done on any fields of User, including the related fields? If there is a way beyond the typical JPA annotations I would love to learn about it.

EDIT: below a bit more details and added more fields to the above entity to make it clearer.

So if I were to change only the phoneNumber field, the updateRecords() function would automatically run because of the @PreUpdate annotation, and then would update the phoneNumberChanged field because the logic has checked that phoneNumber is indeed different from the one from loadState.

If I were to change both phoneNumber and addresses fields then the updateRecords() function would also automatically run, which would see that both addresses and phoneNumber were changed and alter the fields accordingly.

However, if I change only addresses the PreUpdate would not be triggered and so the addressesChanged field would not be updated, even though the addresses list has been changed. I am looking for a way to detect when changes are made to any field of the User entity, so that function can be called and run properly.

Comment: In this case one might call User.updateRecords()  in PreUpdate of Address, assuming a ManyToOne-association from Address to User

Comment: That wouldn't persist changes on the User entity itself though would it? Sorry I didn't make that clear but updateRecords() would be changing fields on the User entity itself even when other related fields are changed.

Comment: You could look into observers if you want to do something like that, but I'm not quite sure if that's the best option for your situation. I see you are cascading your addresses so I don't understand why you don't save your User instead of the address. Could you maybe provide a bit more context as to why your address entity is saved and not your User, as it seems like the phone number of the User has changed.

Comment: @PaulD I am saving the user, but when only the address is changed on the user (e.g. adding a new address to the list of addresses) the PreUpdate annotation isn't triggered. 
```
{
    "phoneNumber": "old number",
    "addresses": [
        {
            "street": "old street"
        },
        {
            "street": "new street"
        }
    ]
}
```
In the above example updateRecords() wouldn't be triggered

Comment: @janlothar I fail to understand why the phone number would need to be updated? If you are saving the User and the phone number hasn't changed, but one of the addresses has, why should the phone number change, is there something in the address that is changing the phone number?

Comment: @PaulD Sorry maybe I wasn't clear enough about what the updateRecords() function should do, the code I've shown is just a snippet of the entire User class which includes many other fields and lists such as name, username, etc. The function should run whenever a change is made to User which will then check which fields have been changed by comparing them with the loadState. This works totally fine and the function is run whenever a change is made to the User, except when a change is made to only the addresses field.

Comment: So you want to have a functionality where both, the current addresses as well as the previous addresses are saved and whenever a new address is saved you want to save the old one into the `previousAddresses` field or something like that? If that's not the case, could you please provide some kind of use case example where because of the current funtionality you get a problem.

Comment: @PaulD in a way yes, that functionality is already written within keepLastAddresses() which checks if the address has been changed, and then saves old addresses within another field of User. However, when a address is changed on the user the PreUpdate/updateRecords isn't triggered. So I am looking for a way to trigger that function automatically so that I do not have to call it manually

Comment: @PaulD I've added more details to my original question

Comment: Unless it would work for you to just dynamically evaluate the last changed date for the addresses, for example like so: 1. Address has field `LocalDate lastModified` which gets set to current date in its own `@PreUpdate` function 2. User has `getAddressesChanged` with something like `return this.addresses.stream().map(Address::getLastModified).max(Comparator.comparing(LocalDate::toEpochDay)).orElse(null);`, you could implement something similar, but instead of writing the modified check into the getAddressChanged you simply set it in the user after saving the addresses ...

Comment: ... and then save the user again